# Checar si dos objetos de la clase java.util.calendar apuntan al mismo dia sin tomar en cuenta el tiempo

Tags: java, calendar

Estoy tratando de comparar dos fechas almacenadas en objetos de calendario. A la hora de ver si son iguales o menores, o no, no tengo ningún problema, la dificultad surge cuando algunos de esos objetos de calendario tienen una fecha y hora almacenadas, y otros no. Lo que me gustaría saber es si hay una manera de verificar si 2 calendarios tienen la misma fecha sin tener en cuenta el tiempo

Tengo este código:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2018, 1, 28, 7, 4, 0);

    if(cal.equals(Calendar.getInstance())){
        System.out.println("hoy");
    }
```

Comment: Hola, sería bueno que añadas más información (¿qué errores/dificultades recibes?) y el código que llevas hasta el momento. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes convertir el calendar a date y darle formato y solo tener la fecha sin tiempo y después esa fecha convertirla nuevamente a tipo calendar por ejemplo:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */
public class CalendarDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Convertimos Calendar a Date
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

            Date dateCalendar = calendar.getTime();
            Date dateCalenda2 = calendar.getTime();

            System.out.println(dateCalendar);

            //Damos formato a la fecha
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");

            String dateS = sdf.format(dateCalendar);
            Date dateD = sdf.parse(dateS);

            String dateS2 = sdf.format(dateCalenda2);
            Date dateD2 = sdf.parse(dateS2);

            System.out.println(dateD);

            //Convertimos el date calendar
            calendar.setTime(dateD);
            calendar2.setTime(dateD2);

            //Calendar sin tiempo
            System.out.println(calendar);
            System.out.println(calendar2);

            //Comparamos las 2 fechas
            System.out.println(calendar.equals(calendar2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
run:
Resultado comparacion: true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta me fue muy útil :)

Comment: @ArturoRuizPascual si te fue uti, considera votar positivo y marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo